# Wordpress. XSTORE. Добавление Youtube видео

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Попросили добавить видео в магазин на вордпрессе.
Добавил блок в Xstore (Custom HTML 03)
В него вставил текст "Дети. Талант. Воспитание" и такой iframe

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JH05sSI_pIY"
 title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write;
 encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

В превью редактора слева, видео появляется. Но на странице его нет. В коде страницы также никакого iframe нет.
Не могу понять в чем проблема.
[image: XSTORE]